# Submit Spark jobs via User Interface

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

Is there any way to submit Spark jobs  via YARN on some UI or even through IntelliJ way written apps.

Best work arounds for company mode style of submitting jobs.

We are using Apache Ambari where we installed Yarn, Hadoop, Spark. Ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cloudera's Hue (Hadoop User Experience) UI to submit a jar for scala/java jobs or py file for Python jobs: http://gethue.com/how-to-schedule-spark-jobs-with-spark-on-yarn-and-oozie/

Comment: This is actually not to bad. I'm checking it and give you feedback afterwards.